# Opening outlook 2010 through vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook.application

I want to send email using outlook 2010, windows 7 & IE8 , what is code required to get the "Outlook.Application" object?.

I tried with 
CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  but getting error "Object Required"

Comment: yes, you will need to create object like
Set oolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set email = oolApp.CreateItem(0)

Comment: CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  is returning Error no 424(object required)

Comment: what you have to do ?
Do you want to send Email or What?

Comment: For your information-IE has nothing to do with this

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code :-

```
' Create email object
  Set oolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set email = oolApp.CreateItem(0)
  email.Recipients.Add("abcaashn@gmail.com")

  ' Create the body of the email
  MailBody = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD W3 HTML//EN"">"
  MailBody = MailBody & "<HTML>" & vbcrlf
  MailBody = MailBody & "<HEAD><TITLE>No Invoices</TITLE></HEAD>"
  MailBody = MailBody & "<BODY>" & vbcrlf
  MailBody = MailBody & "<B>For Your Information</B>,<BR><BR>"
  MailBody = MailBody & "This is Sample Email.<BR><BR>"
  MailBody = MailBody & "</BODY></HTML>"

  ' Send the Email
  email.Subject = "No Invoices Issued"
  email.HTMLBody = MailBody
  email.Send
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This simple code.

This will help you till opening the Outlook and navigate you to Inbox

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNamespace.Logon "Default Outlook Profile", , False, True
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
objFolder.Display
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email using CDO which is the subsystem that Outlook uses.  You can find more information in my article [Sending Emails Using CDO in WSH](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Sending-Emails-Using-CDO-in-WSH/) on ASP Free.

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

' Set Email Headers
objMessage.From = "sender@mymail.com"
objMessage.To = "abcaashn@gmail.com"
objMessage.Subject = "No Invoices Issued"

' Construct Email Body
objMessage.HTMLbody = "<b>For Your Information</b>, <br><br>" _
                    & "This is a Sample Email.<br><br>"

objMessage.AutoGenerateTextBody = True

' Set Server Settings
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.mymail.com"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Send
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for me:-

```
Public Sub runOutlook
 Set oolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set objNS = oolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set email = oolApp.CreateItem(0)
 email.Display
 email.To = "yash.tiwari@programmers.io"
 email.Subject = "Test"
 email.HTMLbody = "<b>For Your Information</b>, <br><br>" _
                    & "This is a Sample Email.<br><br>"              
 email.GetInspector.WindowState = 2             
End Sub
```