# Opening outlook through vbscript

Tags: vbscript, qtp, outlook.application

I want to send email using outlook 2010, windows 7 & IE8 , what is code required to get the "Outlook.Application" object?.

I tried with :

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
```

but getting "Object Required" error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening outlook 2010 through vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391849/opening-outlook-2010-through-vbscript)

Answer (score 0):

"Object required" is vbscript's way of telling you that you tried to call a method of something which isn't an object, most likely it's NULL (or `Nothing`). The only object you're working with is `objOutlook` so probably `CreateObject` failed. Check to be sure that Outlook is registered correctly (The following registry key should exist `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Outlook.Application\CLSID`).

Another problem may be if you have a 64 bit version of office installed, since QTP is a 32 bit application it can't create 32 bit objects (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429477/cannot-use-createobject-from-vb-scripts-on-windows-7)), although that refers to **InprocServer** s, I'm not sure if it applies to **LocalServer** s

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using something like CDO.

[Sending Emails Using CDO in WSH](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Sending-Emails-Using-CDO-in-WSH/)